# XGBoost vs. Gradient Boosting Difference

Tags: boosting

I read this [article](http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/01/23/a-kaggle-master-explains-gradient-boosting/). Are (Stochastic) Gradient Boosting and Extreme gradient boosting the same if: I use Gradient Boosting with

- List item  constant step length phi_m=1 for all m=0,...,M
- List item  the squared loss function as a surrogate loss
- List item   no cost-complexity parameter gamma